# Wordpress alternatives for WP cron

Tags: wordpress, server, cron

As you see in the title, I'm looking for an alternative to WP cron.
As everybody knows (or should know): WP_cron only runs when people are using the wordpress site.
F.e.: You setup a cron each 15 minutes, but nobody visits your site in the past hour, nothing happened.

I'm looking for an other solution then server-cronjobs (like directadmin and cpanel),
because I build my own plugin that will be added to different wordpress-sites.

I found cron-job.org , a free service. But... Free isn't really a stable cooperation.

Anybody else who has suggestions or knows services?
Or should I start my own cronjob-server, as part of my service?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to actually use standard cron to execute your `wp-cron.php` file at specific intervals. For instance, adding the following to your crontab would execute the Wordpress cron script every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /WORDPRESS_INSTALL_DIR/wp-cron.php
```

If you setup a real cron job then I also think you should tell Wordpress not to execute the `wp-cron.php` file automatically by adding the following to the bottom of your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Comment: But... It would take some work for the user who installs the plugin. And that is something what I don't want to set as a requirement for the users.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that you were developing a plugin. I understand the problem.

Comment: You could look on the following repository which might be helpful to fire off you own request to handle stuff that needs to be done: https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing. I think you should be able to create a background task that will repeat itself at a specific interval using it.